# Trying to plot Poisson Point Process MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to obtain a plot similar the one provided below:

```
clear all
clc
L1=10 ;
L2=10;
intensity=2;
parameter=L1*L2*intensity;
N=poissrnd(parameter,1,1);
x=unifrnd(0,10,1,N);
y=unifrnd(0,10,1,N)
scatterplot(x,y)
```

I get the following error

Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar
values.

Error in scatterplot (line 60)
if ((fix(n) ~= n) || (n <= 0))
 [image]

Any ideas to why I obtain something like this?

Comment: i get a plot if i use scatter not not scatterplot

Comment: Ok Ill try it.@chris

Comment: @chris thanks it works, do you happen to know how one can draw the lines between the points?

Comment: google --> "help scatterplot" ... Or am I wrong?